# Using CONCATENATE in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, insert, sql-insert

I am currently in the process of merging two databases together for work and I am doing this by using Excel to generate my INSERT statements.  The reason I am using Excel is because I have 1500+ records which I do not feel like writing that many INSERT statements for.  I will give you a little background on my setup:

[image]

As you can see, I am setting up my INSERT Statement in the above screenshot.  Once completed it would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO "database name"("columns") 
VALUES("values")
```

Below the row I have depicted in my above screenshot I have somewhere around 1500+ rows with 50+ columns.  As you can see I am all set up except for the values portion of the INSERT statement.  To set this up, I am using CONCATENATE to grab all the values from my first row to complete my first insert statement.  This is where I am encountering some troubles.

[image]

To make my INSERT statement work, I need to have my cell values in the following format:

"00064","PPMeetME","test","test", and so on.  But if you look at the above screenshot that is circled in red, I cannot get the data to confine to this format.  I've tried all sorts of different character placement and I am not sure if it is even able to be accomplished but is there any way to set my CONCATENATE statement up so that it will look like how I just mentioned?

(Ex: "00064","PPMeetMe","00001","Test" and not "00064,PPMeetMe,00001,Test")

Please let me know if anything is unclear and I will attempt to further clarify.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

-Dave

Comment: In what form are you getting this data?  Is it a text file?  If so, why not use the Import Wizard?  Is it from some other database? If so, why not use an insert select?

Comment: I basically just copied the data from my one database and pasted it into an Excel spreadsheet.  My reasoning for this was so that if I could get the Values column to be setup correctly, I could simply drag the column down and it would take care of setting up my insert statement for each of the 1500+ rows.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Not really, if you are just looking to copy one database to another, there are so many ways that dont require manual manipulation of an excel file.

Comment: I tried using an INSERT SELECT within microsoft sql but I kept getting Identity Constraint issues and a bunch of other conflicts so I figured If I could set each INSERT statement up like this that I could just run them all and it should be able to insert line by line, hopefully avoiding all those errors the INSERT SELECT statement caused

Comment: use the import wizard and have the data source be a table in your other database.  You will probably have to edit the mappings to make sure that you're not over writing constraints and such, but its a much more reliable way to go IMO.

Comment: Most SQL accepts either single or double quotes as text wrappers. If you switch to single quotes it is a lot easier to wrap in the double quotes necessary for an Excel formula. With your text values in column A, use `="('"&A1&"'"` in B1 then `=B1&",'"&A2&"'"` in B2 and fill down. Finish it off with a closing bracket.

Comment: Why are you not using **[SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)** to transfer the data from one database to the other? There would be no transfer of data to excel, and you can use the mapping feature to not only decide which tables receive which data, but which columns go into which columns. Right click on the Database in the destination, select **tasks** and then **Import data**

Comment: @SeanCheshire echos my feelings.

Comment: @SeanCheshire Actually this looks like a good route to take.  I have just never used this method before so I wasn't sure that it existed.  I went through this process.  Everything looks fine and tells me that all 1501 of my rows transferred, but when I query the database they were supposed to transfer to I do not see any of those records.  Any ideas?

Comment: no rights to select?  have you refreshed the table list (if you created a new table)? counted records (selct (*) from TableName) to check the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to perform concatenation in Excel. You can use the Concatenate formula or you can use `&` between each value you want to concatenate. Since you need to include double quotes around your VALUE terms you can use formula `=Char(34)` to return a double quote. You can do either:

```
=char(34) & A1 & char(34) & "," & char(34) & A2 & char(34) & "," & char(34) & A3 ... & char(34)
```

or

```
=Concatenate(char(34), A1, Char(34), ",", char(34), A2, ...char(34))
```

This can get a little ugly, you may want to consider putting the full string `","` in a seperate cell. Just put this in a single cell (IV1, for example): `=char(34) & "," & char(34)` and then your concatenate formula would look like either:

```
=char(34) & A1 & IV1 & A2 & IV1 & A3 & ... & char(34)
```

Or

```
=Concatenate(char(34), A1, IV1, A2, IV2, A3, IV3, A4.... ,char(34))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  This does seem to achieve the effect I was looking for.  I will accept this answer because it does address my original question.  I did however find an easier way to accomplish my overall goal and that was to use the Import Data functionality in Microsoft SQL Server.  Much appreciation for the insight into the Concatenate function in Excel.

Comment: Im glad to hear you went with ssis. Inserting a handful of records with this metjod is reasonable but 1500 insert statements is stretching it...